# When is a function who is defined on two disjoint sets are continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Okay so let $f$ be a function, $A$ and $B$ two sets that are disjoint.

$f$ is continuous on $A$

$f$ is continuous on $B$.

My teacher told me that $f$ is continuous on these two disjoint sets if and only if they are mutually separated, meaning no one contains the boundary of the other.

I couldn't understand the reason behind this. Could someone help out?

Comment: I'm not super qualified in math, but I think your teacher is wrong. That definitely happens. For instance, say $ f = 0 $ for all arguments. Then it is continuous on any domain. Perhaps you could get a true statement if you made $ f $ arbitrary - in other words, if you said "for *any* f that is continuous on two disjoint sets A and B, then the two sets do not overlap at the boundary iff f *must* be continuous overall"

Comment: I'd have to think about whether that is true, but I think that's your best hope of salvaging the idea of the post

Comment: The "only if" direction holds with a universal quantification over the function. If for all $f \colon A \cup B \to \mathbb{R}$, the continuity of $f\lvert_A$ and $f\lvert_B$ implies the continuity of $f$, then $A$ and $B$ are separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "only if" direction does not hold.

If the domain of $f$ is the union of two separated sets, it is disconnected. Let $(X,\tau)$ be a disconnected topological space and $(Y,\upsilon)$ another topological space. Suppose that $f:X \to Y$ is continuous on $U$ and $V$ where $U,V$ are disjoint open subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$. We can separate $f$ into two mappings: $\phi = f\restriction_U, \psi = f\restriction_V$. Then $\phi \in C(U,Y),\psi \in C(V,Y)$. If $W \subseteq Y$ is open, then $f^{-1}[W] = \phi^{-1}[W] \cup \psi^{-1}[W]$ is the union of two open sets, and thus open. This shows that $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

That's not actually completely true.

Suppose that $f$ is the constant function $f(x)=1$ on both $A$ and $B$. Then $f$ is going to $A\cup B$-continuous no matter what happens with $A$ and $B$.

The following two things are true however:

---

If $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous on  $A$ and $B$ and $\overline A\cap \overline B=\varnothing$ the $f$ is continuous on $A$ and $B$.

The proof of this is going to be different depending on whether you are working on metric spaces or topological spaces.

Proof for topological spaces:

Every $A$-open set is also $A\cup B$-open. To see this take an $A$-open set  $U$, notice that $U=U'\cap A$ for some open set $U'$. Notice that $U=(U'\cap (X\setminus \overline B) ) \cap (A\cup B)$. And so $U$ is $AB$-open.

Proving that $f$ is $AB$-continuous is now easy, given an open $V\subseteq Y$ that $f^{-1}(V)\cap A$ is $A$-open and $f^{-1}(V)\cap B$ is $B$-open, so by hypothesis both are $AB$-open and so their union is $AB$-open, and their union is precisely $f^{-1}(V)\cap (A\cup B)$. So $f$ is  $A\cup B$-continuous.

---

If $\overline A \cap \overline B\neq \varnothing$ then there exists a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ that is continuous on $A$ and $B$ but not on $A\cup B$.

Proof: I suffices to take the function $f(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Pick a point $x$ such that $x\in \overline A \cap \overline B$. Notice that every open set $U$ containing $x$ satisfies that $\{0,1\}\subseteq f(U)$. This is a contradiction, since we can find an open set $V$ containing $f(x)$ such that at least one of $0$ and $1$ is not in $V$.

Comment: I'm working with metric spaces by the way.
Can you give an example when they are not continuous though?

Comment: No, if $f$ is continuous on $A$ and $B$ and you have $\overline A \cap \overline B=\varnothing$ then $f$ is continuous on $A\cup B$.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely false: an easy general method for making counterexamples is take $A$ and $B$ as disjoint subsets of some larger topological space $X$. Then take a function $f^*:X\rightarrow Y$ that is continuous, and restrict its domain to $A\cup B$ to get a new function $f:A\cup B\rightarrow Y$. This function is continuous because $f^*$ was. To make it a counterexample to your teacher's claim, all that you require is that $\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}\neq\emptyset$ (they are not separated).